# Saving database to SDcard

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to save my sqlite database to the SD Card.I tried a couple of things but i couldn't figure it out and some gave me errors,for example it couldn't find the table though it was creating the database on the SD card.
I ended up deleting everything...

What do i need to add or change to save to he SD Card ?
To make it clear,i'm not trying to copy it to the SD card,i'm trying to save it on the sd card instead of  the internal storage.

Here's my database so far.

```
public class Backup_DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DB_NAME = "backup.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION_NUMBER = 1;
private static final String DB_TABLE_NAME = "backup";
private static final String TAG = "CountriesDbAdapter";
private final Context mCtx;
private Backup_DB mDbHelper;
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
static final String DB_COLUMN_1_NAME = "country_name";

static final String DB_COLUMN_3_NAME = "country_price";

private static final String DB_CREATE_SCRIPT = "create table "
        + DB_TABLE_NAME
        + " ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,country_name text unique,country_price REAL)";

private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDBbackup = null;

public Backup_DB(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION_NUMBER);
    this.mCtx = context;
}

public Backup_DB open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new Backup_DB(mCtx);
    sqliteDBbackup = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO: Implement onUpgrade

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDBbackup) {
    Log.i("onCreate", "Creating the database...");
    sqliteDBbackup.execSQL(DB_CREATE_SCRIPT);
}

public void openDB() throws SQLException {
    Log.i("openDB", "Checking sqliteDBbackup...");
    if (this.sqliteDBbackup == null) {
        Log.i("openDB", "Creating sqliteDBbackup...");
        this.sqliteDBbackup = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }
}

public void closeDB() {
    if (this.sqliteDBbackup != null) {
        if (this.sqliteDBbackup.isOpen())
            this.sqliteDBbackup.close();
    }
}

public void insertCountry(String countryName, String countryPrice) {

    sqliteDBbackup.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + DB_TABLE_NAME
            + "(country_name) VALUES('" + countryName + "')");

    sqliteDBbackup.execSQL("UPDATE " + DB_TABLE_NAME
            + " SET country_price=" + countryPrice
            + " WHERE country_name='" + countryName + "';");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLiteOpenHelper isn't built for creating external database. In the SQLiteOpenHelper construtor, context is passed in and it is used to create files in the package folder. Have a look at the source code [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase%28%29) . You can however create in internal first, then exporting it. Remember to add permissions.

Try this helper class I wrote [DBAssetHelper](https://github.com/wtsang02/DbAssetHelper)

Export:

```
new AssetDatabaseHelper(this,"test.sqlite").exportDatabase("/flder_toExport/canBerenamedhere.sqlite");
```

Comment: Seriously ? Weird.Oh well,thanks.I thought it was possible,never thought it wasn't,heh.